# too slow scrolling GridView android when I use resource background on layout

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-listview, android-gridview

Let me explain my problem.

The GridView scrolling is too slow when I use resource background on Relative root layout.
my background file size is 114KB.

I used **android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"** or **android:overScrollMode="never"** with no success.
this is my xml code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:background="@drawable/bg"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<GridView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="125dp"
    android:id="@+id/useful_applications"
    android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    android:overScrollMode="never"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:numColumns="4"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I use ArrayAdapter with holder pattern.

anyone can help me?

**Update 1:**
this is my adapter getView that I used holder pattern

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    UsefulApplicationHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView =LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.component_application_icon, parent, false);

        holder = new UsefulApplicationHolder();
        holder.icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        holder.score = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.score);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (UsefulApplicationHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    Apps info = getItem(position);
    holder.icon.setImageDrawable(info.getIcon());
    String score = info.getScore();

    if (Integer.valueOf(score) > 0) {
        holder.score.setTextColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
        score = "+" + score;
    } else if (Integer.valueOf(score) < 0) {
        holder.score.setTextColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
    } else {
        holder.score.setTextColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.light_gray));
    }

    holder.score.setText(score);

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the adapter/getView code?

Comment: No one? please, @Salem